# Eliminar ocurrencias en un texto

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo que eliminar desde `"a las.. "` para dejar solamente la fecha, en Python.

```
21-MARZO-2017 A LAS 1600 HRS
31-ENERO A LAS 1300 HRS.
30-ENERO-2017 A LAS 1600 HRS.
20/02/2017 A LAS 1200 HORAS (MEDIODíA)
17-FEBRERO A LAS 1200 HRS (MEDIODíA)
18-NOVIEMBRE A LAS 1600 HRS.
18-ENERO 2017 A LAS 1500 HRS.
31-ENERO-2017 A LAS 1600 HRS.
16-MAYO-2017 A LAS 1500 HRS.
09-FEBRERO-2017 A LAS 1500 HRS.
30-MARZO A LAS 1600 HRS
```

Probé con la función `strip()` pero no funcionó.

```
x = "31-Enero-2017 a las 1600 hrs."
y = x.rstrip("a las")
print y
```

Comment: Buenas Pablo, te recomiendo poner el codigo que intentaste con `strip()`  para que pueda orientarte tambien por que no te funcionaba. Un saludo

Comment: x = "31-Enero-2017 a las 1600 hrs."
y = x.rstrip("a las")
print y

Comment: Añdelo a la pregunta mejor que en los comentarios. El problema de strip es que su funcionalidad es para quitar caracteres especificos y no frases. [ejemplo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm). un saludo, me alegra haberte sido de ayuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar este código:

```
x = "21-MARZO-2017 A LAS 1600 HRS!"
y = x.find(" A LAS")
print x[:y]
```

Explicación:

Con el `Find` buscas la ubicacion de `" A LAS"` (importante el espacio antes de la "A" para que te lo borre tambien) y guarda el indice en `y`

Con el `x[:y]` estas diciendo que corte el `substrig` a partir de `y`

Resultado:

> `21-MARZO-2017`

Answer (score 1):

Esto también te podría servir para tus ejemplos:

```
x = "31-ENERO-2017 A LAS 1600 hrs."
print(x.split("A LAS")[0])
```

`Split` devuelve una lista de todas las palabras de acuerdo a un separador. En este caso el separador es "A LAS".

Como la primera palabra de la lista es la fecha, escojo el primer elemento 0 de la lista que obtuve.

Comment: Esto no funcionaria para todos sus ejemplos `"18-ENERO 2017 A LAS 1500 HRS"`

Comment: oops tienes razón, ya lo corrijo a un caso más general